Neovim automatically indents line when typing '>' in insert mode
I am coding in Scala with nvim-metals. When i type '>' in insert mode on some lines it automatically indents it one step to the right. This is quite annoying because it happens when i type '>' and only '>', other shift combinations are fine. This is how it looks like when i type '>' in insert mode, it moves a tab to the right.
Initially I thought the issue was with mappings that I had so I ran :imap looking for anything connected to '>' but there was nothing unusual.
Then, I tried to disable nvim-metals by commenting out the plugin but the issue was still there.
Disabling plugins one by one didn't help either.
I tried running Neovim without any source file with $ nvim -u NONE and this time it worked without indenting after '>', so I figured the issue was somewhere in my init.lua file. I tried creating an empty minimal.lua file and running $ nvim -u minimal.lua but the issue was, again, there.
Changing the terminal emulator or shell didn't help.
I figure, because the issue persists with an empty config file, that the problem is with some Neovim setting. I tried disabling autoindenting and everything other that was somehow related to indenting but it didnt help.
The issue isn't with my keyboard or how Neovim interprets my keystrokes because when I run :echo getchar() and press '>' it returns 62.
